# Every figure is not in the right place

Tags: floats

I'm very new to latex and I've been trying to write a summary on an internship I did, but every figure I used is in the wrong place, I've tried to use [h!] and [htb] but it didn't seem  to change anything. I would really appreciate any tips or direct help
PS: all the figures are in the last page  of the chapter.

Here's the code :

```
\textbf{Introduction} \\[0.5cm]
Ce chapitre sera dédié a la modélisation du datawarehouse . On expliquera premièrement la base étudiée .En suite on définira notre  schéma, les tables et les mesures.

\section{Analyse de la base de données de GIPA}
\textbf{Aperçu} \\[0.5cm]
Ce chapitre sera dédié a la modélisation du datawarehouse . On expliquera premièrement la base étudiée. Ensuite on définira notre  schéma , les tables et  les mesures.
La base de GIPA est composée de 3 tables :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Table Clients : contient les informations des clients
    \item Table Articles : contient les informations sur les articles
    \item  Table Facturation : comprend les détails individuels de chaque facture enregistrée 
\end{itemize}


\subsection{la Table Clients} 
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=20cm]{clients.png} \\[2cm]
        \caption{Champs de la table Client} 
        \label{fig:table_client}
    \end{figure}
On remarque que la table Clients contient plusieurs champs dont la plupart ne sont pas nécessaires a l'analyse. On note les champs indispensables :\\

\begin{itemize}
    \item CodeEntite : Represente l'id du site où le client a fait sa transaction
    \item CodeClient : Un Code unique affilié a chaque client 
    \item Client : le nom du client
    \item Region : la région du client
    \item Tel : le téléphone du client \\[0.5cm]
\end{itemize}

\subsection{La table Articles}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=20cm]{article.png} \\
        \caption{Champs de la table Articles} 
        \label{fig:table_articles}
    \end{figure}
les champs indispensables :

\begin{itemize}
    \item CodeEntite : Représente l'id du site oùle client a fait sa transaction
    \item CodeArticle : Un Code unique affilié à chaque article 
    \item Article: le nom de l'article
    \item CodeLigneProduit: la ligne de produit de l'article
    \item LigneProduit: le nom de la ligne \\[0.5cm]
\end{itemize}

\subsection{la Table Facturation} 
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=20cm]{fact.png} \\[2cm]
        \caption{Champs de la table Facture} 
        \label{fig:table_fact}
    \end{figure}
les champs indispensables :

\begin{itemize}
    \item CodeEntite :Code de l'entité ou la transaction a eu lieu
    \item CodeClient : Code du client acheteur
    \item CodeArticle : Code de l'article acheté
    \item NumFacture : Numéro unique de la facture
    \item NumCommande: Numéro unique de la commande par le client
    \item TauxEscompte : taux de l'escompte
    \item TauxTVA : Taux de tva
    \item QteLivree : quantité de biens livrée pour le client
    \item QteFacturee : quantité de biens facturée par le client
    \item PrixUnit : prix de vente unitaire
    \item TransportUnit : coût de transport unitaire
    \item AutreFrais : Frais supplémentaires \\[2cm]
    
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Conclusion}
On remarque donc que les tables contiennent plusieurs champs non nécessaires à notre projet, donc le schéma n'est pas optimisé.

\section{Choix du modèle}

Puisqu'on n'a pas besoin de deux table faits , le schéma en constellation ne sera pas pris en considération.
Le choix se fera donc entre le schéma en étoile et le schéma en flocon de neige.\\[0.5cm]

\textbf{Avantages du Schéma en étoile} :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Simplicité des requêtes
    \item  Performances des requêtes 
    \item Agrégation Rapide 
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Inconvénients du Schéma en étoile :}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  Redondance des données
    \item Risque d'atteinte a l'intégrité des données élevée \\[0.5cm]
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Avantages du Schéma en flocon de neige :}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Les données sont uniques
    \item  Stockage réduit pour les dimensions \\[0.5cm]
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Inconvenients du Schéma en étoile :}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  le nombre  de jointures engendre une baisse de performance
    \item La complexité est plus élevée en raison des jointures\\[0.5cm]
\end{itemize}
On optera donc pour le modèle en étoile pour sa simplicité et la performance.



\subsection{Modèle du DataWarehouse choisit}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Dimension Client : Contient les champs nécessaires déjà expliqués 
    \item Dimension Article : Contient les champs nécessaires déjà expliqués 
    \item Dimension Region : Contient les champs relatifs aux régions de chaque client y compris son adresse et le lieu de transaction
    \item Dimension Temps : Contient les champs relatifs aux informations de temps de chaque article et client
    \item Dimension facture : Contient les champs nécessaires déjà expliqué avec l'ajout de 3 mesures :
    \begin{itemize}
        \item CA : Chiffre d'affaires (prix de vente * quantité vendue de chaque facture) 
        \item Dépenses : La somme de tous les frais de la facture
        \item Bénéfice : la différence entre le CA et les dépenses
    \end{itemize}
    \item Faits Resultat : Notre table de faits qui regroupe les champs primaires de chaque dimension avec l'ajout des mesures CA , Dépenses , Bénéfices \\[2cm]
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=20cm, height=20cm]{schema.png} 
        \caption{DW utilisé} 
        \label{fig:table_schema}
    \end{figure}
    
    
\textbf{Conclusion} \\[0.5cm]
Dans ce chapitre, on a étudié les données à analyser et réalisé un datawarehouse qui contient les dimensions nécessaires ainsi que la table de faits et ses mesures.
```

Comment: The only purpose of the `figure` environment is to allow its content to move, so what you describe sounds like expected behaviour and not a problem, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: unrelated, but avoid font change commands and `\\ ` in the text, `\textbf{Introduction} \\[0.5cm]` should be `\section*{Introduction}`

Comment: Welcome to the forum and first things first, it is practically impossible to say where the problem lies. Putting all images on the last is often LaTeX behaviour when the images cannot be inserted in the text. This sometimes occurs when they are too big/there would be too little place left. For instance, you give a height of 20 cm for the first picture. This is probably higher than the typesetting area without margins, so LaTeX does not know where to fit it. Without seeing the pictures and a **minimal** working example that shows the problem, there is not much more to speculate here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i want it to move to where i specified it should be with [h!] , but as i mentionned it is not where i want it to be

Comment: `h` means it can go here, but can not go top of page, bottom of page, or on a page on its own, so normally that generates a warning that it is changed to `ht` so that it can go at the top of the next page if it does not fit here, but usually it is better to do `[htbp]` to give more possibilities (only use `!` in exceptional circumstances)

Comment: Some more things: (1) Several of your figures seem to be a tables. Why not typeset that directly in LaTeX? Even if it's too complicated for that, I would suggest using the `captionof{}{}` ability of `\usepackage{caption}` to insert the figure **as** a table. (2) You consistently give width and height. Do not do that, it can lead to distortions if you do not know **exactly** the width and height of the object. Only provide one, LaTeX will scale the other to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: "i want it to move to where i specified it should be with [h!] , but as i mentionned it is not where i want it to be". This sounds as if you do not want to move them **at all**. The simple solution is, just don't use a float then: `\usepackage{caption}\includegraphics{Figure.png}\captionof{figure}{Caption text}` gives you the same formatting with an unmovable figure.

Comment: `[width=10cm, height=20cm]` will distort the image (better to only specify one dimension) and `20cm` will almost always be too large to fit "here" (unless you have a very large page size, but you have shown no example document)

Comment: Additionally, you are using manual bold-face a lot, e.g. `\textbf{Avantages du Schéma en étoile} :`. This may be better formatted as `\paragraph{Avantages du Schéma en étoile:}`. Note also that when you use `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, you do not have to manually insert spaces before (:!?), LaTeX will do that for you.

Comment: wow thank you both so much for the information you ve given me , i removed the hardcoded height and made the width smaller and added htbp instead of h[!] and it works perfectly .

Comment: Thank you so much again for further advice , i will make sure to look more into them

Comment: It is actually better to let the let the algorithm handle the spacing. I already found three instances where you forgot to manually insert the leading space before ":" in your text!

Comment: sorry if this is an unrealted question , but where do i put the usepackage exactly , it triggers can only be used in preamble when i try to put in on top of the page

Comment: Yes, a `\usepackage{}` always goes in the preamble, I just put it in the queue as the comment window does not allow much formatting. You use `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble and then `\includegraphics{Figure.png}\captionof{figure}{Caption text}` or `\captionof{table}{Caption text}\includegraphics{TableAsFigure.png}` in the main text. The [caption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) also allows a lot of formatting for captions far beyond standard LaTeX.

Comment: will do , thank you so much !